# Pity Votes to encourage Participation

Tags: discussion, soft-question, up-votes

What are our thoughts on upvoting something that is wrong, but showed some time and consideration of the question at hand? Do we upvote a newer user even when he or she gives an incorrect answer, just to encourage them to continue trying?

I am of the opinion that only correct answers should receive reputation boosts, but I have wondered if there is an alternative philosophy regarding up votes.

Comment: +1 Against anonymous downvoters--not by pity.

Comment: I actually agree with you too, tho.

Comment: A good answer that is technically incorrect because of what is essentially a typo is worth upvoting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't upvote anything that is wrong.

In the situation that you are describing, better give an encouraging comment pointing out the mistake. When the answer is corrected, you still can upvote.

Comment: +1. And adding to azimut's answer, if you decide to down-vote leave a comment if you are the first person down-voting. If you find an answer with down-votes and no comments, leave a comment asking the coward who down-voted to leave a comment.

Comment: When you hover over the uparrow, it doesn't say, "this answer is correct," it just says, "this answer is useful." An answer that is wrong can still be useful, if there is enough in it that is right.

Comment: @Pleasedeleteaccount I agree that unexplained downvotes are very annoying and harmful. BTW I think you do not have to leave MO too, they have a special agreement with SE which hopefully protects them from the worst things happening there too; I am not 100 % sure about this though, as I obtained no response to my investigating [comment](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow/970#comment4931_970). However, MO has for sure the possibility to leave the SE network if things become too ... hm ... complicated... Best wishes

Comment: @user17762 Anonymous downvoting isn't cowardice, mind you. Its just a way to get true reviews from other users without worrying about retaliation or that sort.